# Creating row_number that starts over for a subset of data

Tags: sql, window-functions

I'm pretty stumped with my latest issue. Here's how my data looks

```
    ID      Item      Price    Rank
    1        A            1.00     1
    2        A            2.00     2
    3        A            2.00     2
    4        A            4.00     3
    5        B            1.23     1
    6        B            2.24     2
    7        B            4.40     3
```

The problem is when there is a 'tie' (see rows id =  2 and 3) , I want it to be:

```
    ID      Item      Price    Rank
    1        A            1.00     1
    2        A            2.00     2
    3        A            2.00     3
    4        A            4.00     4
```

I know I could do it really easily with a cursor, but I think performance-wise that would be terrible. I tried using window functions like LAG and Row_Number but you're still dealing with row by row decisions.  And I couldn't come up with a way to iterate through and then start over when you get to the next item.

Can anyone think of a better way to deal with this instead of a cursor? Sadly, correcting the source data is not really an option.

Comment: Show us your query. Or your code.

Answer (score 0):

**[Window Functions](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/09/sql-server-2005-sample-example-of-ranking-functions-row_number-rank-dense_rank-ntile/)**

Here you have to use `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank() or rank()`

```
select ID,Item,Price,row_number() over(order by Item,Price)
from Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are looking for both `row_number()` and a `partition by` clause:

```
select id, item, price, row_number() over (partition by item order by price, id) as rank
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try below query:

```
SELECT ID, ITEM, PRICE, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(
    PARTITION BY ITEM 
    ORDER BY PRICE, ID
) AS RANK
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

This will get you output:

```
ID   |   Item    |  Price      |Rank
1    |    A      |      1.00   |  1
2    |    A      |      2.00   |  2
3    |    A      |      2.00   |  3
4    |    A      |      4.00   |  4
5    |    B      |      1.23   |  1
6    |    B      |      2.24   |  2
7    |    B      |      4.40   |  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 In which OrderBy you want


 select id, item, price, Row_Number() over (partition by item order by price, id) as     Row_Number,
    Dense_Rank() over (partition by item order by price, id) as Dense_Rank,
    Rank() over (partition by item order by price, id) as Rank
    from table YourTableName;
```